# Creating a table with specific field parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I struggling to create a table that sets table parameters as well as creating the columns.

I am using `MySQL` server.

I require that the table meets the following criteria:

- The table should be Called `CUSTOMER` with the columns `CUST`, `LOCX`, `LOCY`.
- The column CUST will be a 1 up serial starting 1001 and will be the primary key.
- LOCX and LOCY will contain X and Y Integers no greater than +-11, and will be foreign keys to other tables.

For info: I then intend to add my data to the table using the INSERT INTO function in a separate query that I already have.

Any direction on the construction of a query to create a table meeting the requirements above will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is one of the simplest SQL DDL statements. Have you done any research into this at all?

Comment: I can create the table, I am struggling with the setting of values through a query that also creates the table. I am new to this and I have created my tables using phpMyAdmin and managed to construct all the necessary queries. My problem is that although I have this setup, I need to show the actual SQL and the program does not show this upon creation.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html - manual

Comment: [Is there any way to generate DDL SQL statements from database?](http://superuser.com/questions/562136/is-there-any-way-to-generate-ddl-sql-statements-from-database)

Comment: I believe your question is beyond my knowledge! The database simply consists of four tables that I can make queries against

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new table with a MySQL-GUI if you have problems with that.
These GUI-tools usually provide a New-Table button that also allows you to define your table without writing any code. They are often limited but should be more than sufficient for your needs. there are 1-month trial versions for paid versions and even completely free GUIs so you don't have to buy anything.

after that use the following code to retrieve "perfect" SQL from MySQL:

```
show create table your_schema_name.your_table_name
```

do that a few times and study the code. Soon you will be able to write create-table statements and include more complex column definitions on your own. It will also be easier to understand the MySQL Documentation which can be confusing and somehow intimidating with its completeness for beginners.